# Extract HTML Table ( span ) tags using Jsoup in Java

Tags: java, html, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to extract the td name and the span class.
In the sample code, I want to extract the a href with in the first td "accessory" and the span tag in the second td.

I want to print
Mouse, is-present, yes
KeyBoard, No
Dual-Monitor, is-present, Yes

When I use the below Java code, I get,
Mouse Yes
Keyboard  No
Dual-Monitor Yes.

**How do I get the span class name?**

> **HTML Code**

```
<tr> 

  <td class="" width="1%" style="padding:0px;"> 

  </td> 
  <td class=""> 
    <a href="/accessory">Mouse</a> 
  </td> 

 <td class="tright "> 
    <span class='is_present'>Yes</span><br/> 

 </td> 
 <td class="tright "> 
    &nbsp;<br/> 

 </td>
```

```
<tr> 

  <td class="" width="1%" style="padding:0px;"> 

  </td> 
  <td class=""> 
    <a href="/accessory"> KeyBoard</a> 
  </td> 


  <td colspan="2" class="" style='text-align:center;'> 
    <small>No</small> 
  </td>
```

```
  <td class="" width="1%" style="padding:0px;"> 

  </td> 
  <td class=""> 
    <a href="/accessory">Dual-Monitor</a> 
  </td> 

  <td class="tright "> 
    <span class='is_present'>Yes</span><br/> 

 </td> 
 <td class="tright "> 
    &nbsp;<br/> 

</td>
```

> **Java code**

private void printParse(String HTMLdata){

```
Element table = data.select("table[class="computer_table").first();

Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("td").iterator();


while(ite.hasnext()){

      sysout(ite.next().text());

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Element table = doc.select("table[id=computer_table]").first();
```

Elements results = table.select("td");

```
        for (Element dl : results) {
            if(!dl.text().equals("") && dl.text().length() > 1)
                pNames.add(dl.text());

            if((!dl.select("small").text().equals("")) && dl.select("small").text().length() > 1)
                emails.add((dl.select("small").text()));

            if(!dl.select("span").attr("class").equals("") && dl.select("span").attr("class").length() > 1)
                moneyDollars.add(dl.select("span").attr("class"));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

if you get table element then all you you need is getting span. you don't need to get td becasue you can query using span and still get the same result.  below is the code snippet.

```
Elements span = table.select("span");
    for (Element src : span) {
        if (src.tagName().equals("span"))
            System.out.print( src.attr("class") );
    }
```

but make sure that you got table element.