# How to parse a img src with jsoup?

Tags: android, dom, jsoup

How would i go about parsing this with jsoup?

```
<img src="http://cdn.mos..com//classifications/home-entertainment/gaming/images/CU%20game-420-100.jpg" alt="OnLive - devices don't necessarily need as much under the hood" width="420">
```

I have already connected with Jsoup.connect(URL).get().

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like this.

[Extract HTML Table ( span ) tags using Jsoup in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768951/extract-html-table-span-tags-using-jsoup-in-java/6797637#6797637)

To completely answer your question, you should give the entire html code.